# How to cancel a key action in PreviewKeyDown event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to detect if user presses ENTER key in a TextBox, and if so, then move focus to a button without preforming a click on the button. So far the only way I have found to detect the ENTER key is using PreviewKeyDown event. For now I can detect the ENTER key but when change focus to the button it fires the Click event. In the normal KeyDown event I could use 'e.handled = true / false', but how do I do this in PreviewKeyDown event ?

Comment: [if (SuppressKeyPress)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,10663) => [PeekMessage() + PM_REMOVE](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,10854). Of course, you also have e.IsInputKey there...

Comment: @Jimi thank you for response, getting error when I add this (SuppressKeyPress) is there a using statement or something else required to implement?

Comment: Those are not *suggestions*, those are links to the internal functionality. Do you want the enter key to perform its default action in the TextBox (enter a new line in a multiline TextBox) before you focus the Button? Do you have a multiline TextBox or is it single line?

Comment: ok I will check the links. To answer your question, it is not multiline and goal is to move focus to button when user presses ENTER key while in the TextBox (similar behavior as pressing Tab) the 'e.IsInputKey' works but gives an alert sound

Comment: NOTE: because I am using the 'AcceptButton' property, this seems to stop the 'KeyDown' event from capturing ENTER key, so I have to use 'PreviewKeyDown' to detect the ENTER key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {   
      e.IsInputKey = true;
      button1.Focus();
   }
}
```

Also, to reduce sound effect you can use the folowing event listener

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyValue == 13)
   { 
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, your code is working to supress the click event and add focus but it gives the error sound, is there a way to stop that sound from being given?

Comment: If it is possible for you to use other event listener, the easiest way would be look like:
        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

Comment: Have you tried to detect ENTER inside 'KeyDown' by direct keycode 13 by KeyValue property like this: private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) if(e.KeyValue == 13)  e.SuppressKeyPress = true; ?

Comment: Unfortunately the KeyDown does not detect ENTER key but... if I use both Events with the 'e.IsInputKey=true' then IT WORKS! Just have to add both events! Nice one. Lets adjust your answer so i can accept it. I see this is your first answer in SO, congrats!

Answer (score 3):

This event PreviewKeyDown is fired before the KeyDown event is fired. It only gives your an preview and you can't set the Handled flag.

Use this event for logging logic, shortcut logic because this will be always fired and can't be stopped by setting a Handled flag.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However this is the problem I am attempting to solve. If you have a possible solution please offer.